# Saltstack windows minion did not return [No response]

Tags: configuration, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have been debugging alot and finally posting here- Could you please help here ?

I Have Hyper V box with Ubuntu 16 , and Salt Master & Minion on it up. Now on my base physical machine(Win 10) i installed Salt Minion and registered to Master by accepting key.

When I hit Sudo Salt '*' test.ping 
ab:
   True 
winweb :
    Minion did not return.[No response]

Options : Tried disabling Fierwall in ubuntu & my Physical machine (which has windows Minion) I opened all incoming outgoing ports.

Master , Minnions has Nitrogen 2017.4 version .

Any help on how to debug ? My idea is to Deploy an .NET web app to Windows minion .

Thanks,

Comment: Found the root cause of the issue. I tried reproing the issue by setting up Salt Minion on Azure VM. When i added Outbound ports properly it all worked great.

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the salt command timeout from the default 5 seconds to something like 60.

```
salt --timeout=60 '*' test.ping
```

Your firewall only needs to be open from your minion to your master on TCP ports 4505 and 4506.

Look at the salt-minion's config and see if you can ping the master. If you can't ping, then zmq will not work, and neither will salt.